# Toggle between two numbers via a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dragable width which upon being dragged sets a var;

```
var globaltest = 400;
```

It can also show/hide with animate so set the width;

```
var QSW-SW = $(".Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper").width() == globaltest ? "0" : globaltest;
alert(QSW-SW);
```

The rest...

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper').animate({
   width: QSW-SW + "px"
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    direction: 'left',
    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
});
```

This part breaks my script;

```
var QSW-SW = $(".Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper").width() == globaltest ? "0" : globaltest;
alert(QSW-SW);
```

And no alert comes up of which I placed there as a test.

Comment: why would you ever put a `-` in a variable name in any language?

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid! Hot and humid weather - I'm taking a break! - Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you gotta take a break, otherwise crazy things like this happen. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QSW-SW` is not a valid variable name. Javascript thinks you are trying to subtract. Try using an underscore instead.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid! Hot and humid weather - I'm taking a break! - Thank you!